# When to use jQuery-ui autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I need to create input field that uses db entries to autocomplete user entered values (acceptable are only values that exists in the db).

Can anyone explain me what is jQuery-ui autocomplete benefits doing something like described above over using jQuery, mysql and javascript?

(I am using mysql %LIKE% to search similar words.)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-ui autocomplete is basically a widget which you can add to your front end code base, and instantiate on an input element.  Your back end should return some data in the form of JSON, which you will feed into the widget and the autocomplete functionality will start working.  You do not have to get into the hassle of writing this functionality by yourself.  It is a well tested widget with a lot of examples online, so you can easily find out how to set it up and use.  There are many similar widgets online as well, make sure to choose the one which best suits your requirement.

Comment: I have understand that i need to make a request for the data every time user types a letter. I can get needed information by %LIKE%. What functionality benefits i can get through using jquery-ui autocomplete (specifically)??